# Automating build uploading using xcode or application loader

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

Currently I handle the Apps implementation for over 30 clients, It is quite time consuming to upload the builds 1 by 1  to itunes connect,

I have been looking for  an easy way to automate this but I could not find any.

Anybody in the same situation ?

Comment: Did you check `fastlane` https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane ?

Answer (score 0):

We use [circleci](http://circleci.com) for this.

You may set it up the way so that whenever you push to `develop` branch it will automatically create a build and push it to Test Flight for you. No need to do anything except the setup of the CI.

PS: there are many CIs out there. You may find the one that fits you the most. Some [info](http://thebugcode.github.io/ios-continous-integration-choosing-a-build-server-and-tooling/) about it.